# Upper and Lower Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Given $F(x): [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $F(x) = 0, x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $F(x) \ge \frac{1}{2}, x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Proof/Disproof $F(x)$ Riemann-Integrable!

**My Attempt:**

Consider that,
$$M_i = \sup\;\{F(x): x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$$
$$U(F;P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$$
$$m_i = \inf\;\{F(x): x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$$
$$L(F;P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$$

Clearly from the definition that $M_i \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_i = 0$.
So we obtain
$$U(F;P) \ge \frac{1}{2} \text{  and 
 } L(F;P) = 0.$$

Since $U(F;P) \neq L(F;P)$, $F(x)$ is not Riemann-Integrable.

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is correct except the "Since $U(F;P) \neq L(F;P)$", which should be replaced by "Since $\inf_PU(F;P) \neq\sup_PL(F;P)$". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_integrals

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661360.